# How to differentiate products depending on attributes in a Point of Sale Database Schema

Tags: sql, database-design, point-of-sale

Here is my dilemma, I am building a POS system for a pretty large retailer, they have different products which have different attributes (size, color, etc...).

When they receive the merchandise from the supplier they want to do their own labeling with their own UPC Bar Codes but they also want to differentiate between the different sizes using the code on the article.

Say they received Brand A shirts with 4 sizes S,M,L,XL then they should have different bar codes for each size.

So I thought of having a base code for the article and then concatenating numbers depending on the attributes to have different codes? and if no attributes are available just add 0s

I am storing the sizes and colors as attributes in the database as an (Entity-Attribute-Value). Is their a better way other than having to start concatenating numbers from the attributes to come up with the full code?

Thanks for your help!

**edit-------------------------------------------------------**

I am making the example a bit clearer
so the base code for the shirts is: 9 123456
Then for Color blue is: 789
and then for size S: 012
so the full code is 9 123456 789012

for another article that doesn't have size or color or actually any attribute
the base code would be 9 654321
plus 000000 for the attributes part

this is just for simplicity sake as I can use only one digit per attribute.

The other issue is when linking to the OrderDetails table I need to reference all the attributes to know that the customer actually bought Size S in Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to create a table that stores the bar code as the key.  Then have an attribute for the size and the color.

Comment: I am not sure how it would apply to my problem. can you please read the edit I think it's a bit clearer now

Comment: I just read your edit.  I think I am more confused.  What is your question?

Comment: well the question is: is there a better way to achieve this other than the way I am doing it? :)

Comment: Then I think my original answer makes sense. Store each available combination in a table with the bar code as the key.  Have a column for each attribute (color, size, etc.).   Then you could look up a specific bar code and find it is a Small Blue item.  Does that not address the issue?

Comment: If you still want key value pairs.  Create a table of barcodes and table that associates the barcode rows to the key values.

Comment: yup that's what I came up with. I hit enter in the comment box before I could finish what I was writing. so it got posted! I am accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

Actually @jzd your answer is pretty close but I would like to keep the attributes as key value pair.

The idea is to use and an attribute set and have a bar code associated with each set. here is a rough schema

```
AttributeSet Table:
 AttributeSetId
 ProductId
 AttributeSetName
 BarCode


AttributeUse Table:
 AttributeSetId
 AttributeId

AttributeSetInstance Table: 
 AttributeSetId
 AttributeId
 AttributeValueId
```

Answer (score 0):

if you forget the barcode for a minute...

do you have a database to track this inventory?

are the items stored discretely in this database?

if so, then just add a unique number to the item, called the UPC vale - i recommend not trying to make an intelligent key s\as you are describing

Comment: of course I do. I don't want to create a record for each attribute combination in the database that's all. Otherwise it would be pretty simple to add a UPC value